# How can I move these anchor tags to the right?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I move the anchor tags to the right using `display: flex`? Using `margin-left: auto` on the `li a` doesn't work.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  /* added */
  align-items: center;
  /* added; vertical alignment */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000;
}

li a {
  color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="img/logo.png" width="75" height="75"></li>
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">MY WORK</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">HIRE ME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PROJECTS</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The way you are doing this isn't correct. You should put your logo in a separate `div` and the links in another. This will give you more control over the layout. :)

Comment: if the logo is no link and has no alt attribute filled, then a pseudo element to inser it is just fine ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Margin should be applied on the flex children, here i believe it is the second li

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000;
}

li a {
  color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* update */
li:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="img/logo.png" width="75" height="75"></li>
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">MY WORK</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">HIRE ME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PROJECTS</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

margin can also be achieved from first li

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000;
}

li a {
  color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* update */
li:first-of-type {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="img/logo.png" width="75" height="75"></li>
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">MY WORK</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">HIRE ME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PROJECTS</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Logo could be inserted via a pseudo element if it is only about decoration but interact with the layout

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000;
}

li a {
  color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* update */
ul:before {
content:url(http://dummyimage.com/75x75&text=logo);
margin-right:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">MY WORK</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">HIRE ME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PROJECTS</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately for me :( you were 30 sec faster ... +1

Answer (score 0):

Add `flex: auto` to `img`, remove unnecessary CSS rules and unordered list.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: black;
}

nav > span {
  flex: auto;
}

nav > span > img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

nav > a {
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav > a:hover {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <span><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/75" alt width="75" height="75"></span>
  <a href="#">HOME</a>
  <a href="#">MY WORK</a>
  <a href="#">HIRE ME</a>
  <a href="#">PROJECTS</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: I didn't down vote, though if you add an actual image for the logo, you'll see what happens...so can't blame the one that did downvote, as your solution doesn't work any good